# Can't parse RSS feed with EE 3

Tags: rss, ee3, feedparser

I am using EE 3.0.5 and I am trying to get the first-party feed parser to work. I have installed the module with no problems via the add-on manager. I am using the sample code provided in the docs. I have a template consisting of nothing but

```
{exp:rss_parser url="https://ellislab.com/blog/rss-feed" limit="10"}
<ul>
    {feed_items}
        <li><a href="{item_link}">{item_title}</a></li>
    {/feed_items}
</ul>
{/exp:rss_parser}
```

The feed is valid, but EE returns an empty page, i.e. nothing at all. Any bright ideas? Any logs I could check? Has anybody managed to get the plugin to work with EE 3?

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging, I found the reason: the parser can’t handle http**s** feeds, including EllisLab’s own and fails silently.

**Update:** This might be my own fault. Putting `{if feed_error}{feed_error}{/if}`in my template, I get

```
RSS Parser Error: cURL error 60: 
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

so there might be a problem with my setup. Certainly worth investigating.

**Update 2**: Got it to work. My server didn't have the necessary public keys installed. Following [this advice](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/replies/37017), I was able to get it to work.